# What is the best way to count frequency of integers in a table in Lua?

Tags: lua

This is my code for printing 100 random numbers from 0-32. Now I would like to sort the integers received by their frequency. What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

```
 math.randomseed(os.time()) -- random initialize
    math.random(); math.random(); math.random() -- warming up

    for x = 1, 100 do
        -- random generating 
        value = math.random(0,32)
        print(value)
    end
```

An example of desired output looks like this

```
Output:
0:10
1:5
2:4
3:7
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

The simpler is do an histogram, ie a table indexed by values. Whenever a value is encountered, histogram[value] is incremented

```
histogram={}
for i = 0, 32 do
  histogram[i]=0
end
math.randomseed(os.time()) -- random initialize
math.random(); math.random(); math.random() -- warming up

for x = 1, 100 do
      -- random generating 
      value = math.random(0,32)
      -- print(value)
      histogram[value]=histogram[value]+1
end

for i = 0, 32 do
      print(i,":",histogram[i])
end
```